# Display dropdown menu in zen cart

Tags: php, menu, zen-cart, emmet, zen

I require help of you in zen cart.

i have menu like this in my project

[image: in my project]

I have tho add drop-down option menu in the product and it display some the product like

```
New Arrival
product a
product b
```

like same as below

[image]

i am new to the zen cart i am try my self and doing some googling also but i am not get any proper help

So what should do? How it is possible any idea or any suggestion ?? any plugins or any helps is available?? any customization code??

Thanks in advance
Please Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inbuilt plugins for creating menu.

Please check this : http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=323

Thanks.......p2c